# Как указать путь, не зная имени пользователя?

Tags: python

У меня есть путь: C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\BlenderKit\bin\python\lib\os\images. Надо, чтобы вместо USERNAME было имя пользователя, которое определялось автоматически.

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что эта папка у каждого пользователя будет находиться на рабочем столе?

Comment: @Эникейщик, сейчас это не важно. Можно, например, изменить путь или попросить скинуть программу на рабочий стол. Мне нужно именно то, чтобы скрипт определял автоматически имя пользователя. С рабочим столом я без проблем разберусь))

Comment: Конечно же важно. Если вам нужно имя пользователя, зачем тут ваш код? Если же вам нужно расположение папки, то имя пользователя не имеет значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя пользователя хранится в переменных окружения, доступ к ним можно получить через `os`:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

(Path(os.environ["USERPROFILE"]) / "Desktop").exists()
```

Output:
`True`

Comment: а как это указать в пути?

Comment: `Path(os.environ["USERPROFILE"]) / "Desktop"` это и есть путь *C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop*. Дальше к нему добавляете необходимые вам директории. Конкретно Ваш путь составляется так `Path(os.environ["USERPROFILE"]) / "Desktop\BlenderKit\bin\python\lib\os\images"` Результат можете сохранить в переменную и использовать, как Вы задумывали.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо, получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import os
import sys

print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)

before, after = path.split('\\python\\')

new_path = f"{before}\\python\\lib\\os\\images"
print(f'new_path  = `{new_path}`')
```

Comment: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)